# javadoc 8 can't find class in @see reference, but java 7 did

Tags: java, javadoc

I previously asked this in [javadoc 8 can't find class in @see reference, but java 7 did](https://community.oracle.com/message/12430581#12430581), but that seems to be a dead forum. :(

I have a project with several related projects.  Two of the projects are executable jars with the third, Tools, being classes the two share.  javadoc is having troubles compiling Tools and I can't see why.  It has only happened since I migrated to Java 8.  I never saw this issue with Java 7.  The classes I'm referencing with @see are the correct syntax and name.  But each @see to one of the other jars results in an error and the javadoc tool returns an error rather than succeeding.  If I link from the other jars to Tools' javadoc, @see works just fine.

Can someone tell me what's going on?  I added -link commands which the javadoc tool seems to accept, but it still can't find those classes.  This doesn't seem to be an issue with my IDE (NetBeans) as the error is coming from javadoc itself.

Comment: Note that there is a bug with Javadoc links with Java 8; if your docs are, say, at `http://foo.bar/apidoc`, then Java 8 won't find `http://foo.bar/apidoc`; however it _will_ find `http://foo.bar/apidoc/` (note the trailing /). I have reported the bug a few months back but it still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: I do have -link parameters in the command line for the related jars.  However, they don't seem relevant.  The problem was happening before I added the -link option.  I should also note I'm using relative paths.